# Return the winning row between every pair of rows within dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of NBA games and I have scores, but I want to also have a row that contains a binary value of value 1 if the team won that game. I know it probably has something od the with the 'groupby' function but I am not very experienced with it. Here is the data frame:

[image: A look at the data frame]

Comment: Can you add dataframe as text or code to generate this dataframe?

Comment: @oppressionslayer: look at the game number: the two teams are in consecutive rows.

Comment: Ahhh i see it now

Comment: reflecting @ScottBoston, a text data from df[0:9].to_dict or something similar would be nice to have

Comment: @QuangHoang answered it but if you guys are still curious, here is the scraper I used, the other half is broken tho, because of the inequivalently structured data: https://github.com/HalfWolf22/My-Work-Repository/blob/master/game_scraper.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is sorted as shown:

```
df['Win'] = (df['Total'].iloc[::2]
                .gt(df['Total'].iloc[1::2].values)
                .astype(float)
            )
df['Win'] = df['Win'].fillna(1-df['Win'].shift())
```

Output:

```
   Game  Total  Win
0     1    107  1.0
1     1     97  0.0
2     2     90  1.0
3     2     77  0.0
4     3    111  1.0
5     3    103  0.0
```